# Why does text from Assembly.GetManifestResourceStream() start with three junk characters?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, encoding, resources

I have a SQL file added to my VS.NET 2008 project as an embedded resource. Whenever I use the following code to read the file's content, the string returned always starts with three junk characters and then the text I expect. I assume this has something to do with the Encoding.Default I am using, but that is just a guess. Why does this text keep showing up? Should I just trim off the first three characters or is there a more informed approach?

```
public string GetUpdateRestoreSchemaScript()
{
    var type = GetType();
    var a = Assembly.GetAssembly(type);
    var script = "UpdateRestoreSchema.sql";
    var resourceName = String.Concat(type.Namespace, ".", script);
    using(Stream stream = a.GetManifestResourceStream(resourceName))
    {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[stream.Length];
        stream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
        // UPDATE: Should be Encoding.UTF8
        return Encoding.Default.GetString(buffer);
    }
}
```

**Update:**
I now know that my code works as expected if I simply change the last line to return a UTF-8 encoded string. It will always be true for this embedded file, but will it always be true? Is there a way to test any buffer to determine its encoding?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Probably the file is in utf-8 encoding and Encoding.Default is ASCII. Why don't you use a specific encoding?

Edit to answer a comment:

In order to guess the file encoding you could look for [BOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte-order_mark) at the start of the stream. If it exists, it helps, if not then you can only guess or ask user.

Comment: Is there a way to test the encoding? Since I didn't specify an encoding when I saved the file, I assumed it was the default.

Answer (score 1):

if you try to load xml from assembly you actually need to inspect and skip the byte order mark bytes (drove me nuts):

```
....
byte[] data;
using (var stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(filename))
{
    var length = stream.Length;
    data = new byte[length];
    stream.Read(data, 0, (int) length);
}
if (!HasUtf8ByteOrderMark(data))
{
    throw new InvalidOperationException("Expected UTF8 byte order mark EF BB BF");
}
return Encoding.UTF8.GetChars(data.Skip(3).ToArray());
```

And

```
static bool HasUtf8ByteOrderMark(byte[] data)
{
    var bom = new byte[] { 0xEF, 0xBB, 0xBF };
    return data[0] == bom[0] && data[1] == bom[1] && data[2] == bom[2];
}
```

[More information here](http://www.siao2.com/2005/01/20/357028.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem in net.core
You can let streamreader do the encoding

```
 using (var stream = = a.GetManifestResourceStream(resourceName))
    using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
       return reader.ReadToEnd();
```